# Parsing csv file in pandas - object versus float

Tags: python, csv

I am reading a csv file (well actually '.txt') using:

reader = pd.read_csv('FileIn.txt', sep = None, engine = 'python')

The file has eight columns. The header text properly parses into the correct titles but the variable assignment does not.

The first column variable was parsed as "object" which is correct. The next three columns parse as "float64" which is also correct. But the next three columns which have data otherwise identical to the prior three parse as "object" which is not correct. The last column parses properly as "float64".

The data rows and header row data are delimited with "\t". I get the same result whether I use the above line or "sep = '\t'". What should I look for in the header that causes incorrect assignment?

```
Time     Accel_X Accel_Y Accel_Z Gyro_X      Gyro_Y     Gyro_Z     Sensor Time

02:00.9 -1.2779 1.9999  -0.0432 -32.7301    -25.3372    124.9962    292940117.8
02:00.9 -1.3848 1.9998  -0.0365 -32.2456    -25.1961    124.9962    292947383.2
02:01.0 -1.2147 1.9997  -0.027  -31.8565    -25.4135    124.9962    292956093.9
02:01.0 -0.8055 1.9999  -0.0113 -31.8413    -25.9132    124.9962    292965937.3
```

Time properly determined to be object, Accel_X, Y and Z, Sensor Time as Float but Gyro_X, Y and Z improperly as object

Comment: Can you share a small selection of the data? Hard to tell without seeing it.

Comment: Check if columns that are objects contain something different than numbers.

Comment: For example, if `Gyro_X` is object when you think it should be float, try `df["Gyro_X"].astype(float)`-- it's likely there will be an error, and the error message should show a value which couldn't be converted.

Comment: Okay - that worked - some sort of embedded "non-number" in those columns altered the parsing